# Can an app detect that a file (image) has been copied off the device?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Is there any way for my Android app to know which image files (from mediastore) that have been copied from the phone and onto a computer (normally, via USB)? I'm working on a gallery app, which shows all photos on the device. It would be neat if it somehow could mark the pictures that have been copied off the device -- that these are backed up.

So, is there such a "broadcast event/intent" that can be listened for? Is there any alternative way to detect that a file has been copied through USB, say via some altered timestamp or something?

Comment: In the FileObserver class there is an ACCESS event. maybe that would log when the files are read from storage -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html -- there's a tutorial to try here --  http://www.roman10.net/android-fileobserverthe-underlying-inotify-mechanism-and-an-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event that triggers this. Also you can't see that a file has been copied as it won't change any timestamps etc. as far as I know.

But if you manage the backup mechanism you have access to this information yourself...

Comment: Yes, only, I like the idea that the user can back up his/her photos any which way they like. Personally, I prefer connecting as a file device, and just copy all jpegs from the external and internal dirs (typically the CAMERA_100 folders). Maybe it could be possible to detect a large traffic from these dirs, and my app could ask (notification) "did you just do a backup? Want me to flag all photos?"

Comment: @joakimk yes I get what you want to do, but you can't :) Maybe on root you could read all the trafic in/out of phone and do something. But I don't think that is what you're aiming for.